# Https protocol redirects me to Apache welcome screen instead of my Traccar server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ssl, https

I'm completely new to networking or servers.

My boss wants me to set up a Traccar server. Everything went good until I had to secure the connection with SSL.
I installed a self-signed SSL certificate (which I'm worried is not enough, since my antivirus said it's not trusted right at first connection). However, now if I enter my domain (https://gps.mydomain.com) I'm getting an Apache2 welcome screen instead of Traccar application, which I can still access if I connect via http.
How do I resolve this? Am I even doing this right, especially the self-signed SSL certificate? The server is on Ubuntu 18.04 on a rented VPS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your document root directives are different.  For your SSL cert, just use a Lets Encrypt cert.  Its real, and its really easy to set up.

Comment: I was hoping somebody would tell me how to direct Apache to Traccar directory, since I can't find any sort of index file. I know there's an Apache config file but if I direct it to /opt/traccar I'm just getting a 403 error

Comment: We need to see your configuration files to pinpoint what's wrong.

Comment: What configuration files? Sorry for being this new, sometimes I feel I barely know what I'm doing with this VPS

Comment: `apache2ctl -S` will dump out configuration info that we can use.  Your actual configs should be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and there should be links to the active configurations under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Comment: Here's the output: https://i.imgur.com/RIV2jYf.png

Answer (score 0):

> If I enter my domain (https://gps.mydomain.com) I'm getting an Apache2 Welcome screen instead of the Traccar application, which I can still access if I connect via HTTP.

In Apache, HTTPS sites require separate configuration from the HTTP sites, even if they point to the same root directory (your Traccar application). The reason you are getting the Apache Welcome screen is because you have no HTTPS configuration set for `https://gps.mydomain.com`, so Apache is returning the `default-ssl` HTTPS configuration.

> How do I resolve this?

For Ubuntu specifically, you will probably want to look at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` and edit it accordingly. You will likely want to make a back up before making any changes.

Note that it is possible to copy this file (`default-ssl`) and base an entirely new SSL [virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) off of it (i.e. leave `default-ssl` intact and working "as-is" and create a totally new configuration for `https://gps.mydomain.com`).

**Minimal SSL Virtualhost Example**

If you decide to keep `default-ssl` intact and create a new SSL virtualhost, below is the minimal amount of information required to create a working SSL virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName gps.mydomain.com:443
#ServerAlias gps.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/path/to/traccar/application"
ServerAdmin example@localhost

SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire

SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/your/certificate/file.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/your/key/file.key"

#Required by the first SSL virtualhost - Example
SSLProtocol TLSv1

</VirtualHost>
```

Save this file as e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gps.mydomain.com-ssl` (or whatever you like). If you do choose this option, don't forget to:

- Run `sudo a2ensite example_filename` to "enable" the site (this creates necessary symlinks).
- Run `sudo apachectl configtest` to make certain the there are no errors in your configuration. You should see `Syntax OK` after running the command.
- Restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2` for your changes to take effect (this step is also necessary if you simply modify `default-ssl`).